# Getting error while installing Varnish Cache

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, varnish, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on AWS EC2. While installing varnish cache server I am getting following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  varnish-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  varnish
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/543 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,681 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package varnish.
(Reading database ... 92641 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../varnish_4.1.3-1~jessie_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking varnish (4.1.3-1~jessie) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu12) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up varnish (4.1.3-1~jessie) ...
Job for varnish.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status varnish.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript varnish, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package varnish (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 varnish
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have used following command to install varnish

```
sudo apt-get install varnish
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output of the command (and what you post carefully) you seem to have missed

> Job for varnish.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "**systemctl status varnish.service**" and "**journalctl -xe**" for details.

The line above is key to solving this issue. In particular you should run the commands

```
systemctl status varnish.service
```

which may provide some useful information (but it may not) and

```
systemctl status varnish.service
```

which will provide useful information.

Note you should probably run

```
systemctl start varnish.service
```

and then run the commands in the error message.

Comment: It is unable to read its configuration file

Error: Cannot read -f file (/etc/varnish/default.vcl): No such file or directory

How to solve this?

Comment: How's about creating the fie with some config in it ?

Comment: Is there any tutorial for it?